# Select all and as MYSQL Query

Tags: mysql

I've got my query that works well for what I'm trying to do, but I'd like to expand this and grab all other informatino from the stockpicks table. What it does now is match a user search for stock symbol then queries my database to see if theres a match, but doesn't allow for other data from that table to be used. This is what I have prior to changes:

```
$sqlCommand = "(SELECT id, symbol as sym FROM stockpicks WHERE symbol LIKE '%$get_quote%')";
```

This is what I've been attempting to do and my issue.

```
$sqlCommand = "(SELECT * FROM stockpicks symbol as sym WHERE symbol LIKE '%$get_quote%')";
```

I'm getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'as sym WHERE symbol LIKE '%hig%')' at line 1

As I said before I'd like to simply call all the information in case it is needed instead of just calling on the symbol. I don't want to match the other information to the search, but I'd like to be able to use the other data to output in combination with the match. If this doesn't make sense let me know. Thanks for all the helpful information you all provide. Its invaluable.
Chris

Edit : Table structure is

id  |  Symbol  | entry   |  exit  |  openclosed  |   entrydate

For better understanding I'll include the entire script. I'm trying to have the variables available if it is an open position.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); //this is for debugging, remove if you dont need anymore
ini_set("display_errors", 1); //this is for debugging, remove if you dont need anymore
$searchoutput = "";
$ticker = "goog";

if (isset($_POST['get_quote'])) {
$ticker = $_POST['ticker'];
}

$open = fopen("http://quote.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=$ticker&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv", "r");
$quote = fread($open, 1000);

fclose($open);

$quote = str_replace("\"", "", $quote);
$quote = explode(",", $quote);

$quote_0 = ($quote[0]);
$quote_1 = ($quote[1]);
$quote_2 = ($quote[2]);
$quote_3 = ($quote[3]);
$quote_4 = ($quote[4]);
$quote_5 = ($quote[5]);
$quote_6 = ($quote[6]);
$quote_7 = ($quote[7]);
$quote_8 = ($quote[8]);

echo "<div class='symbol'><div class='quote'>Company: $quote_0</div></div>";
echo "<div class='leftofStocks'><div class='row'><div class='quote'>Last trade: $$quote_1</div>";
echo "<div class='quote'>Date: $quote_2</div>";
echo "<div class='quote'>Time: $quote_3</div>";
echo "<div class='quote'>From Previous: $$quote_4</div></div>";
echo "<div class='row'><div class='quote'>Open: $$quote_5</div>";
echo "<div class='quote'>High: $$quote_6</div>";
echo "<div class='quote'>Low: $$quote_7</div>";
echo "<div class='quote'>Volume: $quote_8</div></div>";

if (isset($_POST['get_quote']) && $_POST['get_quote'] != "") {
$ticker = $_POST['ticker'];
$get_quote = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9?!]#i', '', $_POST['ticker']);

$sqlCommand = "(SELECT id, symbol as sym FROM stockpicks WHERE symbol LIKE '%$get_quote%')";

$sym = strtoupper($sym);
$get_quote = strtoupper($get_quote);
        include_once("storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php");
        $query = mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($count >= 1){
$search_output .= "
<div class='rightOfStocks'><hr />It Looks like <strong>'$get_quote'</strong> is one of our stock picks<hr />


</div>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $id = $row["id"];

   $sym = $row["sym"];
   $sym = strtoupper($sym);
   $search_output .= "

   <div class='rightOfStocks'><h3>Our Pick</h3>$sym<br />
   <br />$$quote_1
   </div>";
                } // close while
} else {
$search_output = "
<div class='rightOfStocks'><hr />0 results for <strong>$get_quote</strong>


<hr /></div>";
}
}

?>                              
                                    <div class="form">  <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>">
                                        Get Quote: <input type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" name="ticker"/>
                                        <input type="submit" value="Get Quote" name="get_quote" />
                                        Enter any valid stock quote (ie. AAPL HOG RIMM):<br></form></div>


                                        <!--left of stock results close--></div><!--left of stock results close-->
                                        <?php echo $search_output ;?>
                                </div>
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM stockpicks **symbol as sym** WHERE, bold part is one of the problem. You'll have to take some reading about sql injection also.

Comment: Could you show your table structures? It looks like you're trying to get information from two tables, and to do that you have to define the column(s) that link related records between the two tables - in other words, the `JOIN` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using an alias the "as" keyword is optional.  So it thinks that "symbol" is an alias for "stockpicks" but then it doesn't know what to do after that.

If it's okay for it to return the symbol field named as is then you just need to omit that part:

```
$sqlCommand = "(SELECT * FROM stockpicks WHERE symbol LIKE '%$get_quote%')";
```

If you actually need the field symbol to be returned as sym, then this should work:

```
$sqlCommand = "(SELECT *, symbol as sym FROM stockpicks WHERE symbol LIKE '%$get_quote%')";
```

Comment: Fantastic. That seems to be what I'm looking for. I now have the ability to grab these other variables. This may be a standard question, but can this be manipulated if it is a varchar? For example if I wanted to add another variable to include any gains based on entry price and current price from the yahoo grabbed data?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your question.  If you're asking about the sql statement itself then maybe try to reword your question and I'll see if I can help.  If you're asking about the php (or whatever language you're using) then you might have to ask someone else.

Comment: Also be aware that the latter sql statement will return the symbol field twice: one called symbol (from the *) and then the one you aliased as sym.

Comment: I'll create another question to avoid confusion. Thanks Brandon. I'll also keep the fact that both syms will load in mind. Is there any situation that you can think of briefly where this might be an issue?

Comment: Generally not.  If you were displaying the data in an editable grid it might be confusing to have it on there twice for example, or if you're working with a really large table the number of columns you return can significantly impact the speed of the query.  Probably not anything you're concerned about here, but just wanted you to be aware.

Answer (score 3):

```
 SELECT * FROM stockpicks symbol as sym WHERE symbol LIKE '%$get_quote%'
```

should be

```
 SELECT * FROM stockpicks as sym WHERE symbol LIKE '%$get_quote%'
```

Typically, you can hunt down mysql errors by looking just before the noted syntax in the error. In this case, `"FROM stockpicks symbol"` is assigning the table `stockpicks` to the pseudonym `"symbol"` so the following `"AS sym"` is syntactically wrong. Consider that the operator `"AS"` is optional in this assignment. `"FROM stockpicks symbol"` means the same thing as `"FROM stockpicks AS symbol"`

It should be noted that the assignment of an alias in this case is pointless since it is not used. But the assignment is the reason for the error.